# How to use Github oAuth in jenkins 2.7.3+

Tags: github, jenkins

I'm playing with jenkins and my goal is to be able to build a project manually or on every commit. I never thought it would be so difficult to set up an jenkins server.

What I did so far.

On github I have added a new OAuth aplication and got `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

Now I have to add somehow these data in jenkins configuration. **But how?** I'm using jenkins 2.7.3. so all examples and tutorials seems to be outdated... For example I cant find `GitHub Web Hook` section in my jenkins configuration.

My installed Plugins:

- Git plugin
- Github Plugin
- GitHub API Plugin
- GitHub Authentication plugin

I'm using two factor authentication, so I cant let jenkins to clone my repository by using login and password.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small tutorial, if you need any help just ask.

**Install jenkins on ubuntu:**

```
wget http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.7.3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i jenkins_2.7.3_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f (for dependencies)
sudo vi /etc/default/jenkins Change HTTP_PORT=8080 to HTTP_PORT=8085 (8085 doesn’t work with stash keep 8080)
sudo service jenkins start
```

Go to http://hostname:8080 => install plugins => continue as admin => start using jenkins
user/password: admin/code copied from the local file

**Configure Git on the ubuntu server:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y git
```

If you don’t have already an ssh key: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

Check that the ssh agent is up:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

Then add the key to the ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Add the public key to github (.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

Then test the connection: ssh -T git@github.com

**Configure Github plugin in jenkins:**

Jenkins home => Manage Jenkins => Manage Plugins => Available => choose the plugins: Git plugin, Git client plugin et GitHub plugin (if you don’t find them, they are already installed)

Jenkins home => Manage Jenkins => Configure System => git => Fill the 2 boxes with username and email

On github => settings => Personal access tokens => create a new token => add a description and choose: admin:org_hook, admin:repo_hook, repo => copy the token

Jenkins home => Manage Jenkins => Configure System => github => add a server => add credential of type secret text and paste the token then save

**Configure Github job to be build after a push:**

Jenkins home => New Item => freestyle project and choose a project name => save

Source Code Management => Git and add Repository URL (ex: git@github.com:username/project.git) and add credentials (github’s username and ssh private key)

choose: Build when a change is pushed to GitHub